# Is it possible to connect Nexus 4 to Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: usb, nexus-4, connection-issues, windows, usb-debugging

I'm trying to connect Nexus 4 (Android 4.4.4) to Windows Server 2012 R2 DataCenter for purpose of debugging from Xamarin Studio.

What I did:

1. Activated Developer Settings
2. Checked USB Debugging
3. Installed Google USB driver from Android SDK Manager

But Windows doesn't see it when I connect by USB cable.

Maybe it isn't possible with Windows Server?

PS. But it's charging and I see connected as MTP in USB computer connection.

**UPDATE:** I tried to connected it to Windows 7 and it's working. But I still have problem with Windows Server 2012 R2.

So question is: should I change some settings in Windows Server 2012 R2 or it is not available to connect Nexus 4 at all to Windows Server?

Comment: Does the phone think it's connected? You get a "USB Debugging connected" notification with a picture of a KitKat if it does.

Comment: no, I don't see any notification.

Comment: Do you have the [SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk) installed? Install adb by running `tools/android` and selecting the latest platform tools and then try running `adb devices` in the `platform-tools` directory

Comment: I have Android SDK Manager. Is it what you mean?

Comment: @Alex The notification for USB debugging shows up regardless of whether ADB is running or connected on the host PC, so my first suggestion is to double-check that USB debugging is enabled on the phone. In particular, note that the on/off switch at the top of Developer Options **doesn't** turn on USB debugging: you need to check the check box labelled "USB debugging".

Comment: yes, just looked again USB Debugging is checked. Maybe it's Windows Server fault? I will check it with Windows 7 at work today.

Comment: I would check in `services.msc` and see if anything sticks out to you that is disabled.  Windows Server is a "core" installation of Windows, with most of the desktop services stripped out.  Something in there is preventing device connections.

Comment: which services should be enabled?

Answer (score 4):

Actually Windows Experience Feature is the answer!

I had the same problem and could not install usb drivers for a MotoG on a win2012 Server, but when I installed Desktop Experience feature, all runs flawlessly, drivers auto-installed and all!

BUT it is a little weird to find it...

Go to:

Server Manager -> Open Add Roles and Features Wizard -> Features -> User Interfaces and Infrastructure -> Desktop Experience

Answer (score 0):

[We just found out](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9388/why-is-my-lumia-not-recognised-when-plugged-into-windows-server-2012-r2/9391#comment11068_9391) that you need to install Windows Media Player through Desktop Experience to get MTP functionality on Windows Server.